# PHP Facebook wallpost tracking

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have such code to post on my friends wall from application

`$args = array(

    ‘message’ => 'my message',

    ‘name’ => ‘This is my demo Facebook application!’,

    ‘caption’ => “Caption of the Post”,

    ‘link’ => $data['view_url'],

    ‘description’ => ‘this is a description’,

    ‘picture’ => $body_all["thumb"],

    ‘actions’ => array(array(‘name’ => ‘View’,

                ‘link’ => $data['view_url']))

   );

  $post_id = $facebook->api(“/”.user_$id.”/feed”, “post”, $args);`

In array $post_id['id'] facebook returned me id of the post(like that: 100003284224348_121820851270722), and then when i wona to track it, and get some info by ID, i ask FBgraph  `https://graph.facebook.com/$post_id['id']` but its return false… i have `publish_permission, read_streem permission` in my application… what i do wrong? why i couldn`t see post in info with id on Facebook graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the graph API GET request is returning `false` this is usually a tell tell sign that there is an access token issue at the heart of the problem. When you are making the GET request ensure you are using your applications access token.

Try it here: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=100003284224348_121820851270722

Comment: all works fine there, graph return me post data. But then i need to parse this page to get my info, it`s not beautifull. When i tried get this data in a such way https://graph.facebook.com/100003284224348_121820851270722 with curl, or get_file_contents it`s return false... how can i use my token to read this info

Comment: use `$facebook->api()` - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/

Comment: $ret = $facebook->api($path, $method, $params); could u tell me what  i must put at this attributes. $method - GET, $params - i put filds of post whitch i need, what should i type in path?

Comment: Try `$path = '/100003284224348_121820851270722';`

Comment: Tried http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-setAccessToken/ ?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a timing issue, where you get back the ID and try to use it before facebook's API can see it.  Try waiting a moment and checking.  Does it come up in the graph API explorer tool?